# Jquery calculation through Inputs Add / Subtract

Tags: jquery

OK... as I am new to JS so dont know how to get out of this. here is my form [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxh9q.png)

I am trying to catch the total security of bottles.

**Total security** = Quantity * 500

which is working fine, but when i enter number in empty bottles the calculation doesn't fits .It should subtract the amount (empty bottles) from total security. I am unable to do that somehow..

here is my code;

```
(function () {
      $('input[name="quantity"]').bind("focus blur change keyup", function ()
           $('input[name="total_amount"]').val($(this).val() * $("#pricevalue").val());
           $('input[name="total_security"]').val($(this).val() * 500);
                        });
                })();   

The above code is working fine... code below is creating the problem

        (function () {

           $('input[name="empty_bottles"]').bind("on keyup", function () {

                          var value = $(this).val() * 500;

                           var test = $("#total_security").val() - value;
                           $("#total_security").val(test);

                        });
                })();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you mean by doesn't fit?

Comment: first time it subtracts the value but when i backspace and enter new value it subtracts from the last value it has.. doesn't gets the value which should be quantity * 500 .

Comment: It's hard to follow the logic when half is missing. Could you please edit the question to include both the HTML and the JS

Comment: more code may confuse you.. I have uploaded the picture for demonstration.. you can just guide me through JS. consider the labels as field names.

Comment: In order to fully assist you a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example is required. [ https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ]

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather:

1. Total Security = (quantity * 500) - bottles
2. Total Amount = quantity * price

If that's correct, then the below code should work.

```
$(document).on('input change',':input',function() {
  var quantity = $('[name="quantity"]').val() || 0;
  var price = $("#pricevalue").val() || 0;
  var bottles = $('[name="empty_bottles"]').val() || 0;
  $('[name="total_security"]').val((quantity * 500) - bottles)
  $('[name="total_amount"]').val(quantity * price);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mou9Ldmu/2/